# How to use purrr to pluck/keep some elements from a list of linear regression fit objects?

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of linear regression fit objects. Let's create it in this example by:

```
c('hp', 'wt', 'disp') %>% 
  paste('mpg ~', .) %>% 
  map(as.formula) %>% 
  map(lm, data = mtcars)
```

What I would like is to keep just the `residuals` and `fitted.values` from each of the regression fit objects, within this same pipeline. I was trying to use the `keep` function, but it doesn't work:

```
c('hp', 'wt', 'disp') %>% 
  paste('mpg ~', .) %>% 
  map(as.formula) %>% 
  map(lm, data = mtcars) %>% 
  map(keep, names(.) %in% c("residuals", "fitted.values"))
```

Error:

```
Error in probe(.x, .p, ...) : length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE
```

How can I perform this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a data frame is wanted as output then use the code below or if a list is wanted omit the `bind_rows` line.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

nms <- c('hp', 'wt', 'disp')
out <- nms %>% 
  set_names(x = map(paste('mpg ~', .), as.formula)) %>% 
  map(lm, data = mtcars) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(fit = fitted(.), resid = resid(.))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

We can simplify this slightly using `sapply` as it will add names and use `reformulate` to generate the formula.

```
out <- nms %>% 
  sapply(reformulate, response = "mpg") %>%
  map(lm, data = mtcars) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(fit = fitted(.), resid = resid(.))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

Comment: Added simplification.